# Beep produced (By internally CPU speaker)

Tags: c

```
putchar(263); // edit: fixed typo, was 264
```

it produced beep (By internally CPU speaker);
How?? (Any Ascii value relation)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking "How does a computer produce sound?" or "Is there an ASCII equivalent to `puchar(264)`?"

Comment: I'm simply used above code then it produced beep. Why and How??

Comment: Please copy and paste all the source file that generated this behaviour.

Comment: Well, there sure is a relation to the ASCII character BEL. That relation is `7 == (264 & 255) - 1`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andrea:: only this code write down in main function.

Comment: Hey buddy:: Why give me minus ??? any reson

Comment: @Manish: no reason. Here's my +1

Comment: @Manish, you copy paste code and you manage to make such a mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putchar` converts its argument to an `unsigned char`, so I suppose that you get the ASCII value of BEL after the conversion.

BEL is the code for making the system bell ring.

Comment: `BEL` is `7` in ASCII. Somehow he got '8' considering he did a `putchar(264)` which is equivalent to `BackSpace`, not `BEL`

Comment: But why would it produce BEL = 7? 264 & 255 = 264 & 127 = 8 = BACKSPACE.

Comment: I suppose it was a mistake while copying the code, or I would not be able to explain this behaviour. :)

Comment: `puchar` is a typo; why assume `264` isn't?  `putchar(263)` does, in fact, produce a beep.  `putchar(264)` prints a backspace character.

Comment: @Wooble:: You are right. thanks 2 all

Comment: STACK-OVERFLOW... Awe-Some. I love it n all members

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
printf ("\a") ;
```